# delay render due to slow state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've issue with a flickering when rendering something in a component.

Says I have a prop x which has value of 'a' or 'b'.  and some state change outside of the component will make it become a, a, a, then b, b...

my component has this logic

```
{x === 'a' && <div>do this</div>}
{x === 'b' && <div>do something else</div>}
```

but since it's not an async change, I don't have loading state. How can I make sure I don't see the flickering?

Comment: The code you wrote shouldn't flicker. Are you sure `x` doesn't take any other value than a or b?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie it takes a or b only but when I log it it's a, b, b, b so I see the part where {x === 'a' && <div>appear</div>}

Comment: I don't understand. Your code will show "do this" when `x` is a, and "do something else" when `x` is b. Isn’t that what you want?